# SQL Query Builder

Tags: python, sql, open-source

I am looking for a SQL Query builder  for python (just like in matlab). I am a beginner and can not write one myself (yet..). Do you know of a open-source query builder written in Python ?
Thanks
Arthur

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to when you say you need an SQL query builder for "Python". Do you mean to say you need an ORM like SQLAlchemy (http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to connect with databases without having to write SQL statements yourself?

Answer (score 8):

I have used the [python-sql](https://code.google.com/p/python-sql) library and am very happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

in [SQLObject.org](http://www.sqlobject.org/) there is one see [SQLBuilder documentation](http://www.sqlobject.org/SQLBuilder.html), to build SQL programatically.

As others are suggesting, you might also want to look at ORM systems such [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) ,[Django ORM](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/) or [SQLObject.org](http://www.sqlobject.org/) itself.