# Dynamic SQL query WHERE clause using pyodbc best practice

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am trying to generate a SQL query like

```
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName
 FROM Names  
 WHERE (FirstName LIKE '%FNameA%' OR FirstName LIKE '%FNameB%' ....OR FirstName LIKE '%FNameN%')
  AND (LastName LIKE '%LNameA%'OR LastName LIKE '%LNameB%'..... OR LastName LIKE '%LNameN%')
```

dynamically in python and run it on a Microsoft SQL server using pyodbc. I just wanted to know what the best practice is to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities here.

E.g for queries with a known number of inputs I can use bound parameters to escape any inputs into the query

```
"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE colx = ? AND coly = ?", (x, y).
```

Is there a way to use parameters to construct the first example name search query with an arbitrary number of "Fnames" and "LNames" ?

Comment: You have to create the query string with the required number of parameters dynamically.

Comment: Parameters aren't substituted inside quoted strings. It need to be `LIKE '%' + %s + '%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
if($x){ $value[] = $x}

if($y{ $value[] = $y} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE colx = ? AND coly = ?";     

$stmt ->pdo->prepare($sql);  

$stmt->execute($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct when you say you should use bound parameters to prevent SQL injection. You can simply build up your SQL in a for loop if you want:

```py
firstNameSql = []
for name in firstNames:
    firstNameSql.append('FirstName like '%?%')

sql = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Names WHERE (" + firstNameSql.join(' OR ') + ")"
```

Although, I would recommend looking into a more fully featured ORM that gives you a query builder. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5650837/1393498) for ideas.